# disable email activation only for users who registered via hybridauth module

Tags: users, emails, authentication-authorization

I've faced a problem, I use hybridauth module + original registration module in Drupal 7. And I want to disable email activation for users who registered by hybridauth module(because they use already activated social account), and still retain enabled email activation for users who registered by original registration module. Thanks in advance!

Comment: how would you know that the user is registered through auth and not regular registration process?

Comment: I don't know exactly, but I think there is a way to do it. For example, user who registered via hybridauth has identities in his profile page on tab "hybridauth"...